# hide button add without hiding button + in a subgrid in dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to hide the button add without hiding button + in a subgrid. To explain, I want to let the button lookup which permit to associate an existing record 
but without the possibility to click on new and creating new associated record.
I want to do this only on one subrid without affecting other subgrid of the form or other subgrids of the origine entity.
Is this possible in the CRM pleased?
I have ribon workbench and I dont know how to do this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Shouldn't you do this with CRM permissions? Give `Associate` permission, but not `Create` permission

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting 'Append' and 'Append To' permissions and disabling 'Create' permission. [Here](http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/03/18/definitions-append-and-append-to-dynamics-crm/) is good explanation of two.

EDIT: I don't think that there is a way to hide '+' button in your case. One thing that I can think of here is field security mechanism - it will not remove '+' button but it will prevent creating entity X from subgrid in entity Y or to be more specific it will prevent creating entity X with filled entity Y id.

Comment: I think that The problem is that if I do it with CRM permissions all the entity X will be concerned by this rule limitation, while i want just to do that in just one subgrid related to this entity, and not all subgrids of entity X, Do you agree with me ?

Comment: So you want to be able to create entity X from everywhere but from specified subgrid related to entity Y? Also you want to have possibility to relate entities X and Y normally?

Comment: Thanks a lot pen2 for your answer, I will try that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the subgrid buttons, by editing the ribbon (it's part of it). By providing a custom EnableRule or Command, you can overwrite the buttons behaviour - the same way as any other button in the ribbon.

You probably know it, but a nice tool to work with the ribbon is the Ribbon Workbench.

[Stable Silverlight version](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/80806-download-ribbon-workbench-for-crm-2011-2013-2015)

[Beta 'HTML5' version](http://develop1.net/public/post/Ribbon-Workbench-2016-Beta.aspx)